# RapidJSON get member name of Value

Tags: c++, rapidjson

Wondering if it's possible to extract the name of a `rapidjson::Value` directly from it.

For instance, assume we have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "name":
    [
        { /*some data*/ },
        { /*some more data*/ }
    ]
}
```

And I retrieve the "name" array from it:

```
rapidjson::Value& myJSONArray = document["name"];
```

Can I retrieve "name" back from that `Value`? Something like this:

```
std::string memberName = myJSONArray.GetMemberName(); // returns "name"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible because an array may not be within an object.
You may use iterator.

```
Value::MemberIterator itr = document.FindMember("name");
string n = itr->name.GetString();
Value& v = itr->value;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this. I get "value is private in this context."

Answer (score 0):

Iterators for object has `name` and `value` properties

```
std::pair<bool, std::string> iterate_items()
{
   constexpr std::string_view stringJson = R"([ {"k1": "v1"}, {"k2": "v2"}, {"k3": "v3"}, {"k4": "v4"} ])";
   // Wrap input stream for rapidjson reading
   rapidjson::MemoryStream memorystreamFile( stringJson.data(), stringJson.length() );
   rapidjson::Document documentJson;                                        // Create root rapidjson object

   documentJson.ParseStream( memorystreamFile );                            // Parse json file
   if( documentJson.IsArray() == true )                                     // Yes, we know it is an array :)
   {
      for( auto const& it : documentJson.GetArray() )                       // iterate array
      {
         if( it.IsObject() == true )                                        // They are all objects
         {
            auto const& _name = it.MemberBegin()->name;                     // get name
            auto const& _value = it.MemberBegin()->value;                   // get value
            std::cout << _name.GetString() << _value.GetString() << "\n";   // dump it
         }

      }
   }
   return std::pair<bool, std::string>( true, std::string() );
}
```

[Tutorial with RapidJSON](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7133&link=%5B%5B%229F60D5FEDE8E41CC986C10147F0AD2F7zoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7133%5D,%5B%2271C91DEE3C5A4FDC8EC1114C7C18033Bzoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7133%5D%5D&rows=50)